# Why is $\mu(E_{1}) + \lim\limits_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \mu(E_{n+1} -E_{n}) = \lim\limits_{N \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, self-learning

I am learning Continuity of Set Functions. There is a proof about a theorem which I don't fully understand. more specifically, I can't see why $\mu(E_{1}) + \lim\limits_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \mu(E_{n+1} -E_{n}) = \lim\limits_{N \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_{N})$, Maybe it is clear for some of you, so any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

I have also attached the image about the theorem and its partial proof. [image]

Comment: Hint: $\mu(E_{n+1}-E_n)=\mu(E_{n+1})-\mu(E_n)$.

Comment: @Wojowu, Thanks, but I couldn't progress further from $\mu(E_{1}) + lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \mu(E_{n+1}) - lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \mu(E_{n})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the telescope sum trick for sets / measures.
By additivity, we have
$$
\mu(E_{i+1}-E_i) + \mu(E_i) = E_{i+1},
$$
hence
$$
\mu(E_1) + \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(E_{i+1}-E_i) = 
\mu(E_1) + \sum_{i=1}^n ( \mu(E_{i+1}) -\mu(E_i) ) = \mu(E_n).
$$
Since $\mu(E)>-\infty$ for all $E$, no indefinite expressions appear.

Comment: Thank you so much! @daw I have just googled the telescope sum trick!  you have saved me a lot of time!